# Is it worth to prepare for Magento 2 Certification in 2018?

Tags: magento2, certification

I'm new to using Magento and wish to get into Magento 2 development. I've got some questions—

1. What languages should one learn before getting into Magento 2 learning/development?
2. What are some good online resources (for beginners) to learn Magento 2?
3. Is getting a Magento 2 certificates (Associate Developer and/or Professional Developer) worth it?  The two exams together cost more than $450 and definitely demand a lot of time in preparation.
4. Whether these certificates are actually valuable in IT industry (as of 2018)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will focus on question 1. only.

Languages: `PHP7` and `ES6`. `SQL`, not that much, although it never hurts.

`JSON` is a must, `LESS` is good to know.

`HTML`, `XML`, `CSS` goes without saying.

`Knockout` and `RequireJS` are very desirable to know.

On installation and deployment topic, it is a good idea to know `git` and `composer`.

Any `CLI` experience will do, although is good to be familiar with at least basic linux (`cd`, `pwd`, `rm`, `cp`, `find` etc).

On conceptual level, try to learn design patterns as much as possible and various paradigms like: `SOLID` principles, `MVC` patterns, `Dependency Injection`, `Observers` and so on.